# Using different resolution for two overlaying layers?

Tags: overlay, resolution, gis-principle

If I have 2 layers: one satellite image (15m resolution) and one relief (about 30m resolution).

Can I overlay the relief with some transparency over the satellite image?

It obviously "works" but is it wrong?

Comment: What end result are you trying to achieve? Are you processing the data or just displaying it?

Comment: I will only display it. And it looks good, but I don't know if I miss something, because usually you try to work with the same resolution.

Comment: Ok, i have to adapt my answer: first of all I will display it, but maybe I'm going to do a supervised classification with it (but this only concerns the satellite image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just displaying the data, it's fine as long as the viewer can interpret what they're looking at. That's the point of a map -- to clearly convey spatial data. Data is rarely perfect. Sometimes you have to work with what you have, such as a lower-resolution DEM.

Aesthetically speaking, it might look a little odd to have a transparent raster overlayed on another raster. You could try converting your DEM to contours and overlay those on your satellite image. Ultimately, you have to decide what conveys your data most clearly.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. but despite the odd looking, is it also 'correct'? I mean could I report the resolutions to my supervisor or will this not be ok?

Comment: Yes, you can report it to your supervisor. Your data is a representation of the real world. Nobody familiar with the data expects it to exactly represent the altitude of every location in the data set. Yet, the DEM is "correct" insofar as it is an accurate representation of the mean elevation within each ~30m pixel. We accept these sort of tradeoffs when we choose to use lower resolution products. Unless your supervisor will give you money for higher resolution data, you've done the best you can.